# laravel select query create dynamic column name not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am  trying Laravel join query to select the column dynamically but below line is returning error.

> \DB::raw('table3.ElrA'.($effectiveYear'.-YEAR(table1.eff_date).'))

table3 having columns like this ElrA1, ElrA2 .....
common part is "ElrA" I am just making trailing number dynamically to create whole column name but it gives me err like  "ElrA202-YEAR(table3.eff_date) is not a column". can you please suggest any solutions.

```
$query = DB::table('table1')
->join('table2', function($join) {
$join->on('table2.policy_period_id', '=', 'table1.id');
$join->where('status','1');
})
->leftjoin('table3', function($join) use($effective_date)
 {                       
 $join->on('table3.class_code', '=', 'table2.code');
 $join->where('table3.date', '=', DB::raw("(select max(`date`) from table3 where date <= '".$effective_date."' limit 1)"));
 })
->select(\DB::raw('table3.ElrA'.($effectiveYear'.-YEAR(table1.eff_date).')))                    
->where('table1.mod_id',$id);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the error code, it says clearly that laravel try to find column ElrA202-YEAR(table3.eff_date)

What happen is because you make mistake in this part

```
'table3.ElrA'.($effectiveYear'.-YEAR(table1.eff_date).'
```

the exact part is in this one

```
'.-YEAR(table1.eff_date).'
```

because you use '' and it will parsed as string and not the variable that you want

I don't know why you will use dynamic column, but it is really not a good idea, because as the documentation says, it's very vulnerable with sql injection attack because there is no parameter binding in dynamic column. But if you know what you are doing then it's okay

Comment: i do not understood exactly what i need to change. can you please explain in more detail what i need to do  ? Thanks